# Передача статических значений в универсальный шаблонный класс

Tags: c#, классы, generics

Как я могу передать в шаблон не только тип, но и конкретное значение, например, целочисленное? К примеру, есть такой код:

```
public class Sample <T, size>
{
    private T[] arr = new T[size]; // =(
    ...
}
```

Как через size передать число?

Спасибо!

Comment: Дмитрий Нестерук про это записывал видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xOPAesZ_eZg
Посмотрите, идея очень простая :)

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, Вам пригодится такая идея. Объявите атрибут, свойство которого содержит нужное Вам число, и пометьте этим атрибутом класс, который будете подставлять в качестве Generic-параметра. А в статическом конструкторе Generic-класса читайте атрибут у T.

Comment: Это конечно решение поставленной (надуманной) задачи, но увидев подобную реализацию в проекте я бы посчитал ее костылем и выкинул.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем? Такое не является возможным в CLR. Передавайте размер в конструктор класса.

Comment: Такое возможно в C++, и это очень удобно! Мне, например, хотелось бы сразу указывать размерность массива в классе, без использования инициализации в конструкторе. Это удобно.

Comment: Используйте типизированные списки вместо массивов.

Comment: @Asen В с++ это не столько для удобства сделано, сколько для всяких фишек и шаблонной магии. В шарпе такое просто нельзя. И насчет удобства спорный вопрос. Все равно же приходиться указывать размер, либо в конструкторе, либо при параметризации шаблона.

Comment: В шарпе такое невозможно? Это новость...жаль =(

Comment: @Asen

- Из-за отсутствия `typedef'ов` прелесть от записей типа `Sample<MyType, 26>` и `Sample<MyType, 136>` выглядит довольно сомнительно.

- Судя по всему, вопрос возник из академического, а не практического интереса, поскольку в реальной жизни такое применение дженериков довольно бессмысленно.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, ну да, этот вопрос возник из интереса, а не на практике...ну что ж, нет, так нет.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, зачем? В шарпе это более чем глупо... Смысл дженерика в том, чтобы обобщать, а не конкретизировать. Если заранее известен размер массива, воспользуйся статическим полем, константой. Если надо создаваться динамически - конструктор тебе в руки (в том числе и статический конструктор). Не знаю как в плюсах, а в шарпе это просто более чем нелогично...